# Source IP(recorded at service end, outside cluster) when talking from pod to a service outside Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

Probably a noob K8s networking question. When a pod is talking to a service outside the Kubernetes cluster(ex: internet), what source IP would the service see? I don't think it will be the pod IP (as it is) because NATing involved? Is there some documentation around this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/29/kube-proxy-subtleties-debugging-an-intermittent-connection-reset/#kubernetes-networking-basics):

> For the traffic that goes from pod to external addresses, Kubernetes
> simply uses [SNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#SNAT). What it does is replace the pod’s internal source
> IP:port with the host’s IP:port. When the return packet comes back to
> the host, it rewrites the pod’s IP:port as the destination and sends
> it back to the original pod. The whole process is transparent to the
> original pod, who doesn’t know the address translation at all.

Comment: @Always_Beginner Does the above solve your issue?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor the documentation link definitely helps.